# Receiving corrupt Images over tcp/ip in python via socket.recv()

Tags: image, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi3, python-3.6

I'm trying to stream images from raspberry pi to my windows laptop (python 3.6.3) and receiving corrupt images (more details follow the code) . Following is my code.

Client side:

```
import picamera
import socket
import struct
import time
import io

stream_client= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
stream_client.connect(('192.168.1.106',9000))
print('connected')
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution=(320,240)
camera.color_effects=(128,128)
camera.framerate=18
time.sleep(2)
stream = io.BytesIO()
count=0
start=time.time()

try:
    for i in camera.capture_continuous(stream,'jpeg',use_video_port=True):
        count+=1
        stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<L',stream.tell()))
        stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<h',count))
        stream_client.sendall(stream.getvalue())
        stream.seek(0)
        stream.truncate()
        if(time.time()-start>2):
            break
finally:
    stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<L',0))
    stream_client.close()
    camera.close()
    print('connection closed')
```

Server Side code that Saves corrupt images:

```
import socket
import struct
import io
import cv2
import numpy as np

server_socket= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('192.168.1.106',9000))
server_socket.listen(1) 
print('Server is ready')
(client_conn,client_addr)= server_socket.accept()
image_stream= io.BytesIO()

try:
    while True:
        data_size=struct.unpack('<L',client_conn.recv(4))[0]
        counter=struct.unpack('<h',client_conn.recv(2))[0]
        print('Image Count = ',counter)
        print('Image size = ',data_size)
        if not data_size:
            break
        image_stream.write(client_conn.recv(data_size))
        image= np.fromstring(image_stream.getvalue(),dtype=np.uint8)
        img=cv2.imdecode(image, -1)
        print(image) # just wanted to see how the image data looked 
        cv2.imwrite((str(counter)+'.jpeg'),img)
        image_stream.seek(0)
        image_stream.truncate()



finally:
    server_socket.close()
    print('Exception Detected ! Server Closed.')
```

The above server code saves mostly corrupted image and garbage images and very occasionally the correct images. I tried increasing and decreasing buffer sizes but i think this did not make sense and it did not help either (in-fact it worsened the problem).
I also implemented a server code using the makefile() method and the images that i received were proper.

What i'm thinking is that this problem exists since i'm not buffering the data and directly feeding it to the stream. Which i feel is the only difference between the correctly working server code and incorrect server code.

I'm aware that the sendall() method in client automatically sends over data that is lost(or corrupted ?) and i feel that this re-transmit is not automatically being handled by the recv() method ? could this also be a reason for the problem? Or is there something entirely different happening here ?

In any case, i would like to implement the image transfer code by recv() method, since i believe it would deepen my understanding of the socket programming. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong ? Any help is appreciated.

P.S: This is my first question at Stackoverflow, so i have tried to detail my problem and thoughts as much as possible. If you feel that i should reduce/increase detailing, please do tell me so. cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     image_stream.write(client_conn.recv(data_size))
> ```

You expect `recv` to return all `data_size` bytes. But, the size argument only gives the maximum number of bytes it will read. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv):

> socket.recv(bufsize[, flags])
> ... The **maximum** amount of data to be received at once is specified by bufsize.

You have to check the return value how much data were actually received and then call `recv` again until you have all data, i.e. something like this:

```
while data_size>0:
    buf = client_conn.recv(data_size)
    if buf == '':
        raise Exception("unexpected eof")
    data_size -= len(buf)
    image_stream.write(buf)
```

Comment: but doesn't  `stream_client.sendall(struct.pack('<L',stream.tell()))`  in the client program take care of how much data will be sent to server ? do you mean something like `client_conn.recv(data_size-image_stream.tell())` ? but does'nt it mean i'm creating new buffer( or probably resizing ?) for client_conn.recv() after every transfer of byte ? I'm confused, could you elaborate ?

Comment: Thank you so much ! This solved it. Seems like i misunderstood the documentation. Here's what i did: `while ((data_size-image_stream.tell())>0):
            image_stream.write(client_conn.recv(data_size-image_stream.tell()))
            print('recieved',image_stream.tell())`